# HTML DIV Variable Bootstrap Display Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap with node.js express project. Upon getting variables installed into the theme where the username is (as shown below), There is some sort of invisible gap in the viewing of the code.

```
<!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img id='picture2' src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span id="name" class="hidden-xs">Firstname Lastname</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img id='picture' src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                <p><div id="name2">Firstname Lastname</div>
                  <div id="companytitle"><small>Member</div>since<div id='signupdate'>Nov. 2012</small></div>
                </p>
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Body -->
```

[image]

This image shows the original bootstrap before i added the multiple  tags to change the text with ajax. As soon as i added the `<div>` tags, the visuals of the profile tab parted and started to look like the first image.
[image]

I am unsure of how exactly to get these items to align right on the page, as you can see, it almost appears that the data has some breaks in it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Here is the original boostrap snipped for the profile tab

```
<!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
              <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                  <span class="hidden-xs">Alexander Pierce</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <!-- User image -->
                  <li class="user-header">
                    <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                    <p>
                      Alexander Pierce - Web Developer
                      <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                    </p>
                  </li>
                  <!-- Menu Body -->
```

Comment: Could you clarify where the invisible space is - and what is meant by invisible space?

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the post

Comment: I think it would help if you could create a demo fiddle or something as the problem seems to be style issue. Also the image you replaced appears to be larger .. perhaps you could look into that?

Comment: This is just a long shot as I don't have access to the data as such. However, I have experienced problems with Bootstrap reacting to white-space: when there is a new line then try to add a comment:
 
<last-tag><!--  
--><firsttag>